# How to verify if a request comes from the same project in App Engine? (mixed Flexible and Standard)

Tags: rest, security, google-app-engine, reverse-proxy, microservices

First, a little context on our setup:

In our setup, we have a Google App Engine project with a reverse proxy in the `default` service. It acts as an API gateway to all other microservices in the same project. This was recommended to us by Google engineers.

All requests from clients to these microservices should be routed through this gateway, so we need the underlying services to respect the `X-Forwarded-*` headers when building new URLs. This causes a security problem though: a malicious user could forge the headers to make our application call endpoints in their own domain.

To protect against this, the underlying services must be isolated from the external world. They must only accept requests that come from the same project (which is, the gateway and other microservices).

In App Engine Standard there's a way to [tell App Engine to include a `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps) that validates the project, but we couldn't find anything similar to this in App Engine Flexible. In particular, [the migration guide says nothing about asserting request identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#app_identity).

**How do we assert that a request came from the same App Engine project?**

Is this possible at all in the flexible environment? We'd like to avoid implementing a shared secret (that could leak), or a mechanism where the services have to always check with the gateway if the request came from them :/

Right now we're having to validate in the services themselves that the `X-Forwarded-*` headers adhere to its expected format, which beats the whole purpose of using the headers in the first place.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever figured this out, I'm having a similar sort of issue with Google Cloud Functions and wondering how best to restrict invocation of a HTTP cloud function to only the same Google Cloud project that it is deployed to.

Comment: Google Cloud support told us it wasn't possible right now :/

If your cloud is entirely in App Engine Standard, you can use the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header.

If your cloud is entirely in App Engine Flexible, you can choose to run your application entirely in one region and set a VPN.

But if your application is mixed, you'll run into trouble, like we did :/ So in the end we're using an auto-refreshing shared secret scheme for now, until they release new features =(

Comment: Yeah relying on `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` doesn't work with Google Cloud functions as their cloud function proxy resets its value to tell you that the function was called by it, and will remove anything you set in App Engine or another Google Cloud Function.  Wasted a lot of time on this today, thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: I ended up wondering about using https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/ as well and treating "our" components as API customers of our components too - for now I just set a header in my own code and check it in the cloud function which isn't ideal too as Google Cloud Functions don't support environment variables even though Firebase Cloud Functions do so the value of the custom authorization header ends up in the code :/

Comment: Has this been implemented yet?